# PyCharm is sometimes too heavy

Tags: performance, pycharm

Sometimes, when I chose a new interpreter (especially if its remote interpreter), i find my self waiting for some background tasks such as download pre-build shared indexes or other stuff, while all I want to do is to run my script.
I've used Spyder in the past, and I dont remember having this issue. It has much more functions and background workers, but when I click run to run a script, it simply runs it.

Is there a way to tell PyCharm to ignore everything and just let me run the script? (the button is grayed)